# React Redux: action gets fired but reducer code is not executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm stuck on writing my first react/redux app. As a user I want to add a star to my favorite item via click on the star. After that, the starcount should update. I displayed all the items with map() and use a Card Component to display them.
I can see in the redux tools that my action gets fired when I click on an item and it even gets the right payload (the id of the item I clicked on). But the code I got in my reducer does not get executed (I tried with a simple console.log as well as with more complex code). I cannot figure out where I missed something.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />  
    </Provider>
    
);
```

**App.js**

```
import Card from './Components/Card.js';
import './App.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';

function App() {
  const burgers = useSelector(state => state.burgers);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
      </div>

     <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
       {burgers.map((item) => 
        <Card img={item.image} title={item.name} price={item.price} stars={item.stars} key={item.name} id={item.id}/>
      )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

**Card.js**

```
import './card.css'
import { BsFillStarFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';

export default function Card(props) {
    const { title, price, stars, img, id } = props;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const handleClick = event => {
        dispatch(actions.addStar(event.currentTarget.id));
      };
    return (<div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
            
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
            <div className="card-title">{title}</div>
            <div className="price">Price: ${price}</div>
            <div className="rating" id={id} onClick={handleClick}>
                <div className="star">
                    <BsFillStarFill />
                </div>
                <div className="count">
                    {stars}
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
            
        </div> 
            
        
    </div>)
}
```

**actions.js**

```
import * as actions from './actionTypes.js'
    
export function addStar(id) {
    return {
        type: actions.ADD_STAR,
        payload: {
            id: id
        }
    }
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { sortBurgers, updateStarCount } from './sortBurgers.js';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    starCount: updateStarCount,
    burgers: sortBurgers
})

export default rootReducer;
```

**sortBurgers.js** (my reducer)

```
export const burgers = [
        {
            id: 1,
            image: hamburger,
            name: "Hamburger",
            price: 1.25,
            stars: 0
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            image: baconBurger,
            name: "Bacon Burger",
            price: 2.50,
            stars: 0
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            image: doubleMeatBurger,
            name: "Double Meat Burger",
            price: 3.75,
            stars: 0
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            image: doubleCheeseBurger,
            name: "Double Cheese Burger",
            price: 5.00,
            stars: 0
        }
    ]
  
    export const updateStarCount = (state = burgers, action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
            case action.ADD_STAR:  
            console.log(action.payload.id);
            let starcount = state.map((item) => {
                return item.id
            } );
            let starIndex = starcount.indexOf(action.payload.id);
            console.log(starIndex);
                return [...state.slice(0, starIndex), state[starIndex].stars + 1, ...state.slice(starIndex + 1)]
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

**ActionTypes.js**

```
export const ADD_STAR = "ADD_STAR";
export const TEST = "TEST";
export const INCREMENT = "INCREMENT";
export const DECREMENT = "DECREMENT";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:
sortBurgers.js
action.ADD_STAR

actions.js
action**s**.ADD_STAR

different s

You must import the value of actions.ADD_STR from the actions.js and add this value to swith.
In your code, the value is action.type is checked against the value of action.ADD_STAR, which is most likely undefined

UPD:

1. in card.js -
   event.currentTarget.id is a string.
   Change in actions.js

   ```
   export function addStar(id) {
        return {
            type: actions.ADD_STAR,
            payload: {
              id: Number(id)
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. replace 'add_star':

   ```
        case actions.ADD_STAR:
              return state.map((burger) => {
                  if (burger.id === action.payload.id) burger.stars++;
                  return burger;
              })
   ```

Comment: I tried to do that. Now my reducer code gets executed, but my action does not fire anymore.

Comment: You can show the code from ActionTypes.js
The types must be the same in sortBurgers.js and Card.js

Comment: I added the code from ActionTypes in the post.

Comment: I have completed my answer. The error was in the type of data being transmitted. the fix is indicated with the optimization of the burger search and the increase in the star counter

Comment: Yeah, now I can see the action in the redux tools and the code is executed, thx :) Now I should only fix my UI to reflect the changes (for some reason it does not yet).